# if input code is equal to code, set icon

Tags: php

So, I am making a weather app using php and some weather apis. API that I use is giving me code that says what is the weather like. So, for example, if code is 200, that means that current weather is 'Thunderstorm with light rain'. What I want to do is show an icon for every code.

```
icon-lightning-4 { 200, 201, 202, 210, 211, 212, 221, 230, 231, 231 }
icon-rainy-2 { 300, 301, 302, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 321, 520, 521, 522, 531 }
icon-rainy { 500, 501, 502, 503, 504 }
icon-snowy-3 { 511, 600, 601, 602, 611, 612, 615, 616, 620, 621, 622 }
icon-air { 701, 711, 721, 731, 741, 751, 761, 761, 771, 781 }
icon-sun { 800 }
icon-moon { 800 }
icon-cloudy { 801 }
icon-cloud-3 { 801 }
icon-cloud-4 { 802 }
icon-cloudy-2 { 803, 804 }
```

Above you can see Icon name and codes inside curly brackets. How to achieve this with PHP to show icon instead of code. I am not a PHP developer, but I am learning and that's why I am asking this. Help very appreciated. These icon names on the left are actually span classes that show icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just put the codes into an array and loop through them using the [`foreach`](https://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) construct:

```
<?php

$iconMap = array(
    'icon-lightning-4' => array(200, 201, 202, 210, 211, 212, 221, 230, 231, 231),
    'icon-rainy-2' => array(300, 301, 302, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 321, 520, 521, 522, 531),
    'icon-rainy' => array(500, 501, 502, 503, 504),
    'icon-snowy-3' => array(511, 600, 601, 602, 611, 612, 615, 616, 620, 621, 622),
    'icon-air' => array(701, 711, 721, 731, 741, 751, 761, 761, 771, 781),
    'icon-sun' => array(800),
    'icon-moon' => array(800),
    'icon-cloudy' => array(801),
    'icon-cloud-3' => array(801),
    'icon-cloud-4' => array(802),
    'icon-cloudy-2' => array(803, 804)
);

$icon = '';
foreach ($iconMap as $iconString => $codes) {
    if (in_array($result, $codes, true)) {
        $icon = $iconString;
        break; // stop looping, for efficiency
    }
}
```

I've called the result from the API `$result` here.

What this code is doing:

1. Creating an associative array with the codes corresponding to each icon name
2. Looping through this array
3. For each icon name, it is checking whether `$result` is in the array of codes using [`in_array`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)
4. If it is, it will set `$icon` to be the icon name and stop looping.

If the code is not found, `$icon` will simply be an empty string.

You can use the string `$icon` to output your image, for instance:

```
if (!empty($icon)) {
    echo "<img src='{$icon}.png' alt='...'>";
}
```

Comment: It is returning an empty string even though there is a match with `$result`

Comment: Is `$result` a string or integer? If `$result` is a string then change all of the array elements to be strings (i.e. put quotation marks or apostrophes around them)

Answer (score -2):

Well its hard to give you the right code since there isn't that much there,... But this is what I would do:

PHP:

```
// for the lightning icon...
if ($code == 200||201||202||210||211||212||221||230||231||231){
$image_URL = "icon_lightning.png";
}
```

HTML:

```
<img src='<?php echo $image_URL ?>' width='50px' height='50px'></img>
```

Comment: So i need to loop for every icon? Is there a way to make a parser for this?

Comment: @TheNeosrb There isn't any loop there, You may have been confused since I wrote "for".

Comment: @TheNeosrb Which is why I said confused,

Comment: Okay, but is there a way to make a parser for this?